How to use repository, usecase and repository_impl when working with api
I was implementing clean architecture while development a new app With RestApi , I am having difficulty during implement RepositoryImpl extends from Base Api Repository to call api and pass through DataState checking .
The error shown
The return type 'Future<User>' isn't a 'Future<HttpResponse<User>>', as required by the closure's context
the error in class UserRepositoryImpl method  getUserById(String id)
Code
 import 'package:retrofit/http.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: 'https://api.example.com/')
abstract class UserDataSource {
  factory UserDataSource(Dio dio) => UserDataSource(dio);

  @GET('/users/{id}')
  Future<User> getUserById(@Path() String id);
}


abstract class IUserRepository {   
  Future<User> getUserById(String id); 
}


@Injectable(as: IUserRepository)
class UserRepositoryImpl extends BaseApiRepository implements IUserRepository {
  final UserDataSource _userDataSource;
  UserRepositoryImpl(this._userDataSource);

  @override
  Future<DataState<User?>> getUserById(String id) {
    return getStateOf<User>(
      request: () => _userDataSource.getUserById(id),
    );
  }
}


import 'package:school_app/utils/resources/data_state.dart';
import 'dart:io' show HttpStatus;
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:retrofit/dio.dart';

abstract class BaseApiRepository {
  @protected
  Future<DataState<T?>> getStateOf<T>({required Future<HttpResponse<T>> Function() request}) async {
    try {
      final httpResponse = await request();
      if (httpResponse.response.statusCode == HttpStatus.created || httpResponse.response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
        return DataSuccess(httpResponse.response.data);
      } else if (httpResponse.response.statusCode == HttpStatus.unauthorized) {
        throw DataFailed(DioException(
          response: httpResponse.response,
          requestOptions: httpResponse.response.requestOptions,
        ));
      } else {
        throw DioException(
          response: httpResponse.response,
          requestOptions: httpResponse.response.requestOptions,
        );
      }
    } on DioException catch (error) {
      return DataFailed(error);
    }
  }
}




import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

abstract class DataState<T> {
  final T? data;
  final DioException? error;
  const DataState({this.data, this.error});
}

class DataSuccess<T> extends DataState<T> {
  const DataSuccess(T data) : super(data: data);
}

class DataFailed<T> extends DataState<T> {
  const DataFailed(DioException error) : super(error: error);
}



refectory DataState and BaseApiRepository

what is the return type of _userDataSource.getUserById(id) ? it should be Future<HttpResponse>. but looks like error said that it is 'Future'..

Can you add the UserDataSource related files, I just want to know where you are converting the json into a model class for the api call.

getStateOf method in BaseApiRepository is expecting a Future<HttpResponse<T>> as the argument for the request parameter, but you're passing Future<User> instead.
you need to update the UserRepositoryImpl class to return a Future<HttpResponse<User>> instead of a Future<User>.

I suggest looking at reso coder playlist on the subject. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iYGE_khpXRdJkJEp9WOech

the UserDataSource  class has been added

You should change function return type from:
Future<DataState<T?>> getStateOf<T>({required Future<HttpResponse<T>> Function() request}) async...

to
Future<DataState<T?>> getStateOf<T>({required Future<User> Function() request}) async

because in abstract class UserDataSource you return Future<User>:
  @GET('/users/{id}')
  Future<User> getUserById(@Path() String id);

Or just change return type of your request:
  @GET('/users/{id}')
  Future<HttpResponse<User>> getUserById(@Path() String id);

then this line could remain as it was:
@protected
  Future<DataState<T?>> getStateOf<T>({required Future<HttpResponse<T>> Function() request}) async {...


Dear, When I change to the new code another problem shown
and i want to use the (setState) method as global
Future<DataState<T?>> getStateOf_1<T>({required Future<User> Function() request}) async
    try {
      final httpResponse = await request();
      if (httpResponse.response.statusCode == HttpStatus.created || httpResponse.response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {



ok, maybe this will help you, fix my answer
